# male-male VGA cable wiring

Tags: cables, wiring, vga, pinout

I need to build a VGA cable (assemble connectors to wire).
I need a male-male cable.
Is its wiring straight or cross? (should i connect 1-1,2-2,... or something else)

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware there are coaxial cables in it? http://pimg.tradeindia.com/00327603/b/0/VGA-Cables.jpg

Comment: @jippie: yes; RGB cables are coaxial (but not signals); I just want to be sure that connecting pin 1 from one end of cable to pin 1 of the other end of wire will work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, all VGA cables are wired 1-to-1, whether they are regular male-male cables or the relatively rarer male-female extension cables. The equipment at either end always has a female connector, and they're all wired the same way.

Comment: "The equipment at either end always has a female connector" I certainly remember encountering some projectors and CRTs with male panel mounted VGA inputs during the 2000s, perhaps I saw some oddballs or perhaps it was more common back then. OTOH all the LCD monitors with removable cables i've seen had female inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In fact if you don't need pin 9 (option 5v) you could use an old male to male serial cable.  Whic I have recently done, myself.